# Horizontal Scrolled Site with Fixed Active Navigation?

Tags: jquery, scroll, fixed

I am after something exactly like this really...

http://www.haggsgate.co.uk/contact/

A horizontal scrolling site controlled by two arrows, that only appear when they are needed, faded other times.

But i dont really have a clue where to start.

The addition is i need it to also add an active link to the navigation.

For example on that site, the navigation across the top is all sections from the page and if you click on them it will scroll to that point also, as well as the arrows, also appear active so you know which section your on.

Any tips or tutorials?

Hope someone can help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give a look to JquerTools http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html
With it and some customization you can achieve what you want.

It has nice documentation and is cross browser compat.

hth,
byte_slave

Comment: Yeah been trying with that one but doesn't work how i need it to as that has to be a fixed width, this needs to be open...